# how to redefine environments like \begin{xxx} ... \end{xxx}

Tags: macros

I'm translating some text that use the `comment` package, it's usage seems like that:

```
\begin{en}
 ... some English text
\end{en}

\begin{zh}
... corresponding Chinese text
\end{zh}
```

By using `\excludecommand{en}` or `\includecommand{en}` before `\begin{document}`, we can control the text out or in the final PDF document.

But this too trouble to add `\begin{}/\end{}` for every paragraph, what I want is following:

```
\en{
 ... some English text
}

\zh{
... corresponding Chinese text
}
```

this is much more simple to type. and I create the commands like this:

```
\newcommand{\zh}[1]{\begin{zh}#1\end{zh}}
\newcommand{\en}[1]{\begin{en}#1\end{en}}
```

But this cause compile error like `runaway argument`, how to make it work under this situation by using `newcommand`?

Comment: You can try `\let\OldEn\en`  and use `\OldEn`, instead of `\begin{en}` and `\enden`, instead of `\end{en}`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I think the best way to do things would be to keep the environments and to configure your editor so that with a shortcut it typesets the  environment and puts the cursor in the middle.

Comment: Note that not all environments can be turned into commands (anything with verbatim or ams alignments will cause trouble at least) also in a large document it is a lot easier to see matching begin/end than working out what is ended by `}` any reasnobel editor shoudl allow you to enter \begin{en} \end{en} with 1 or 2 keystrokes

Comment: You can't: The comment environment is looking for the string \end{en} while skipping over the rest of the text. Also it is problematic to put large portions of text in an argument: You can't change catcodes there and so a lot of things (e.g. verbatim) are not possible.

Comment: @Bernard: what I'm planning is sed or awk...

Comment: 1. note that it's `\includecomment` and `\exclude...`.  2. your runaway arguments are because you have an end-paragraph (double-`\n`) inside the command argument; use `\newcommand*` instead of just `\newcommand` ... or keep to 1 paragraph per `\en` or `\zh` command, and have the paragraph breaks outside the commands

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to redefine an existing command `\en` which gets defined when the `en` environment is defined (as does `\enden`).  The solution to redefine *most* environments is to first save the definition of `xxx` as `\OldXxx`:

```
\let\OldXxx\xxx
```

and then redefine the `\xxx` macro using `\OldXxx` and `\endxxx`:

```
\renewcommand{\xxx}[1]{\OldXxx#1\endxxx}
```

[image]

### Note:

- As per the comments, this *won't* work with any verbatim type of environments.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{en}{%
}{%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{en}
 \ldots some English text in environment
\end{en}

\let\OldEn\en
\renewcommand{\en}[1]{\OldEn#1\enden}

\en{\ldots some more English text in macro \ldots}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use just *one* other character for the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{en}{}{}
\newenvironment{zh}{}{}

\newcommand\Zh[1]{\begin{zh}#1\end{zh}}
\newcommand\En[1]{\begin{en}#1\end{en}}

%\renewcommand\Zh[1]{} %%% enable if it should be excluded
%\renewcommand\En[1]{} %%% enable if it should be excluded

\begin{document}
\En{ \ldots some English text in environment (En)}

\Zh{ \ldots some more English text in macro \ldots (Zh)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but with the `\includecommand{Zh}/\excludecommand{En}`, why?

Comment: You can simply redefine the command as empty. Then it throws its argument away. See my edited answer.