# How to redefine environments with \begin{xxx} … \end{xxx}, keeping the same syntax?

Tags: macros, environments

Say that we have an environment that is used like this:

```
\begin{foo}
... code in here
\end{foo}
```

And, without changing the above syntax in our document, we would like to redefine what the `foo` environment does.

For example, say we want to wrap `foo` in a `bar`, so that the *effect* of the above code would be like this:

```
\begin{bar}
    \begin{foo}
... code in here
    \end{foo}
\end{bar}
```

For example, as [suggested in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166468/168344) we can do the following:

```
\let\OldFoo\foo

% in the minimal redefinition case
\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{\OldFoo#1\endfoo}

% in the wrapping w/ bar case
\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{\begin{bar}\OldFoo#1\endfoo}\end{bar}}
```

And this would allow us to do the following:

```
\foo{ ... code in here }
```

However, that's not the syntax we want - it's essentially a new `\foo` command, not redefining `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}`

---

My attempt is the following:

```
\let\origfoo\foo
\let\origendfoo\endfoo

\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{
  \begin{bar}
  \origfoo{#1}
}

\renewcommand{\endfoo}[0]{
  \origendfoo
  \end{bar}
}
```

... but it doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

P.S. Bonus Q: I don't understand where `\endfoo` is coming from. Is `\end{foo}` a syntax shorthand for `\endfoo` in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Yes, `\end{foo}` expands to `\endfoo` and some other things. Could please show us a concrete example? It will be much easier than trying to guess what `foo` does. Depending on the environment, the approach is different.

Comment: You're doing it wrong... there's no need to go from `\begin{foo}`...`\end{foo}` to `\foo{...}` when wrapping `foo` within some other environment. See [this example](https://pastebin.com/AEFqnHHq).

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LaTeX an environment consists of two macros (plus some more code added by
`\begin` and `\end`). `\newenvironment` and `\renewenvironment` define both of
these commands. The following saves the values of `\Foo` and `\endFoo` and uses
those to define another version of the environment `Foo` which also incorporates
the `\begin` and `\end` code of `Bar`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newenvironment{Foo}
  {%
    \itshape
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {%
    \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  }

\newenvironment{Bar}
  {%
    \bfseries
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {%
    \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{Bar}
  Test this
\end{Bar}
\begin{Foo}
  Test this
\end{Foo}
\begin{Bar}
  \begin{Foo}
    Test this
  \end{Foo}
\end{Bar}

\let\FooOrig\Foo
\let\endFooOrig\endFoo
\renewenvironment{Foo}
  {%
    \Bar
    \FooOrig
  }
  {%
    \endFooOrig
    \endBar
  }%
\begin{Foo}
  Test this
\end{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should consider `\ignorespacesafterend`.

Comment: @egreg I don't see any difference when using it. What should be its effect?

Comment: It should be used instead of `\ifhmode\unskip\fi`. It's much cleaner.

Comment: @egreg but it does something completely different (I just tested). The `\ifhmode\unskip\fi` removes a trailing space from the contents of the environment, while the `\ignorespacesafterend` removes the space after the environment. I think the former is better (while being less clean), as one is used to this behaviour (compare e.g. `tabular` the space after `\end` is the one you'd have to comment).